# How many wp-config.php files should I have on the Ubuntu Linux install?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, ubuntu

I followed all the steps to install WordPress on my Linux install. I am using Ubuntu but it seems there are one to many wp-config. php files within the folder.
Could this cause it not establish a connection with the database?
Which on location is the correct one?

The locations they are found are:
etc/wordpress/ wp-config
usr/share-wordpress/ wp-config
usr/share/wordpress/ wp-config-sample

Answer (score 0):

wp-config file should only one. Many files occur installation error below screenshot for wp-config location
[image]